# FB 4.6 Data Services from local XML file - how to advance to next record?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Im using flash builder 4.6 and am building a quiz application where the user is shown questions and answer options from a local XML file.  The XML is being loaded using Data/Services (though I thought about using another method initially)...

How can I 'advance' through xml if I have code like the following:

```
label2.text = "{getDataResult.lastResult[0].Text}";
```

specifically, how do I 
a) get the TOTAL number of records based on the name of a node that represents an array.    then after I have that integer, how do I

b) add 1 to the 0 incrementally to go through all the records?

Comment: Without knowing your XML Data structure it is impossible to help you.  But, generically store the XML in some type of variable (Such as an XMLList or XMLListCollection) and access the data through the usual accessors, such as getItemAt[index].

Comment: Thanks, getItemAt(index) is exactly what I was looking for.  thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as a formal answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your XML Data structure it is impossible to help you.

Generically, you would normally store the XML into an [XMLList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html) or [XMLListCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html).  I recommend an XMLListCollection as a collection class is required when using Spark Lists.  The MX Lists will automatically convert XML or XMLList to an XMLListCollection.

From there, you can get at a specific item using the standard accessors, such as [getItemAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#getItemAt%28%29).